# Get track.stream_url returning garbage

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to stream SoundCloud songs using JPlayer in a Ruby on Rails application. I try to get the stream url server-side using this:

```
@stream_url = client.get(@track.stream_url, :allow_redirects => true)
```

I then try to load this URL using JPlayer like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function() { 
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "<%= @stream_url %>"
      });
    },
    swfPath: "/js",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
</script>
```

But when I load the page, the browser chokes on the URL string. The returned markup and script looks like this:

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: "���DInfo+4F��!$&amp;)+.0368;=@..."
```

That string goes on for much longer than I'll post here.

My best guess is that this is an encoding issue, but I can't figure it out. I've tried in the rails console to debug, but that got me nowhere.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some encoding issues you are facing with.

When I send the HTTP request manually and get the endpoint URL in C#, I don't face the same  problem and the end the endpoint URL of the audio is perfectly fine.

```
public void Run()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TrackUrl))
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(TrackUrl + ".json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
            }
        }

        private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);


            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                this.AudioStreamEndPointUrl = myResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
                this.SearchCompleted(this);
            }
            myResponse.Close();

        }
```

Don't know how that is it applies to Ruby on Rails but you get the idea. 
You can try a similar trick to this one instead of using the client.get method.